# Javascript: localStorage & cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I'm (still) currently working on a project right now, and I need a little help with something. I currently need to use both localStorage and cookies to store information for a form. For example, in my code, I have a textfield that prompts users to enter their name. Once that name is entered, the user will go through three dynamically generated drop-down menus. Once done, a form will appear that will show the name of the user, and ask them to enter their email so they can receive a newsletter.  My question is how can I use both local storage on browsers and cookies to store the name and email?

Note 1: My project has to be optimized for all browsers, which means that I HAVE to use both local storage and cookies.

Note 2: I cannot use the .innerHTML function or jQuery for this project.

Note 3: There is a link in the comments of the JSFiddle demo of my project.

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r22VX/

Comment: Are you allowed to use any third party scripts, libraries or extensions?

Comment: I think only for cookies it's ok, but no jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If browser compatibility is your priority, I would insist on you checking out [**Modernizer**](http://modernizr.com/).  Basically it will allow you to probe your users browser and serve a script accordingly. (also use [**this**](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies) for cookies, because x-browser...)

**Example:**

```
var data = localStorage.getItem(name) || Cookies.get(name);  
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {  
    localStorage.setItem(name, 1)  
} else {  
    Cookies.set(name, 1);  
}
```

You also definitely need to read up on some design patterns for JavaScript ;)  Look up various widget patterns and you will be happy with what you learn.

Comment: oh cool! But I can't use a third party script for local storage. :(

Comment: there's no plugin for the localstorage... Modernizer simply detects if it's available.